# For which $x,y, z$ we have $390=x^3+y^3+z^3$ with $ x, y, z$ integers?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I have done many attempts of computations to get such integers $x, y, z$ for which $390=x^3+y^3+z^3$, but I can't however $390 \neq  4\bmod 9$ or $-4 \bmod 9$  which means there are solutions? Any help?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3%3D930+in+integers) gives $x=13, y=4, z=-11$; presumably permutations of those work too

Comment: Sorry I meant 390 not 930, just a wrong typo

Comment: see wiki entry of [sum of 3 squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes). As of September 2019, $390$ is the second smallest positive $n$ which we don't know whether the equation $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = n$ has a solution or not.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually an open problem. We still don't know whether numbers such as $114,  390, 579, 627, 633, 732, 906, 921$ and $975$ are the sum of $3$ cubes.